# What is a list of common, cheap, real time rendering algorithms?

Tags: raytracing, rendering, algorithm, real-time

I am well aware of the existence of Blinn-Phong shading, which is a great tool when you are doing, for example, modelling algorithms and wan't to focus on the model. In this case a full BRDF result, even if fast, could make it harder to appreciate the geometry you are analysing.

On the other end of the spectrum, we have full BRDF approximations through monte-carlo algorithms and ray traycing. Which give amazing results, but are very slow.

I have tried to look for, but haven't found,a list of commonly used algorithms that have different levels of trade off between quality and speed.

Does anyone know of a resource where I can find some algorithms, their performance and quality?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're referring to here. You conflate lighting models (Blinn-Phong vs. more capable "BRDF approximations") with rendering algorithms (ray tracing) and presumably anti-aliasing (monte-carlo). What exactly are you looking for here? Also, list-questions of this sort are not a good fit for Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: While the question is not very precise I don't think the right way to go about it is to downvote everyone. That's directed to whoever's having a field day with the downvote button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For mostly offline rendering (some of those can be done in real-time, but in the majority of cases not for games, which is changing especially with NVIDIA RTX) you can refer to this: https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ritschel/Papers/GISTAR.pdf
At the bottom there's a very nice table that summarizes the findings.

For more real-time oriented stuff you can refer to this post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/28bs74/realtime_global_illumination_ispm_vs_cone_voxel/

Answer (score 0):

I found a good article from 2009:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/09ea/c60a78c84f9048058cb9518ed30335b86169.pdf

Comment: Could you summarise what you found there? Links like this have a tendency to just die, and then your answer becomes completely useless. Also people don't generally like to download a PDF with no idea of the contents.